# Not able to change SuperTabNavigator tab text's font

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, styles, tabnavigator

I'm struggling with SuperTabNavigator coz I'm not able to change the tab text's font.
My font is a OTF embedded in the application via `@face-font` syntax in my style sheet, and I have used this successfully in other places e.g. spark label.
Then I have defined a style for the SuperTabNavigator referencing the aformentioned font both in term of fontStyle and fontFamily.
No result achieved.

Could you please provide the correct way to change tab text's font in the SuperTabNavigator component?

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify CSS the SuperTabNavigation

```
@font-face {
    src:url("./fonts/YOURFONT.TTF");
    fontFamily: myFont;
}
@font-face {
    src:url("./fonts/YOURFONT.TTF");
    fontWeight: bold;
    fontFamily: myFont;
}

SuperTabNavigator {
        popupButtonStyleName: "popupButton";
        tabStyleName: "firefoxLikeTabs";
        leftButtonStyleName: "leftButton";
        rightButtonStyleName: "rightButton";
        buttonWidth:20px;   
        font-family: "myFont";
        font-size: 11;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, tried this out and it didn't work. 
That's how my css looks:

    '@namespace code "http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/";

    @font-face {
     src: url("font/HELVETICANEUELTSTD-LT.OTF");
     fontFamily: "helveticaLtStdLt";
     advancedAntiAliasing: true;
     embedAsCFF: true;
    }

    code|SuperTabNavigator {
     font-family: "helveticaLtStdLt";
     font-size: 23;
    }'
The IDE also complains about the fact that SuperTabNavigator is never used

Comment: Maybe the FONT is not supported, try another to see if it works FONT style and thus exclude that the FONT is the problem.

Comment: thanks but I don't think the problem is the FONT coz, as I said, I have used the same font elsewhere in the app. Moreover I have other fonts (even TTF) embedded and none of those works.

Comment: I used it as I wrote it works correctly, weird. Sorry I can not help more.